# Сondition for the existence of the subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have an abelian group $G$ of order $m$. And I want to know if there is any subgroup $H$ with order $n$. The condition of the Lagrange's theorem ($m = 0\ (mod\ n)$) seems to be necessary but insufficient.

Comment: Do you know that finite abelian groups can be written as a direct product?

Comment: What examples have you seen of insufficiency?

Comment: @lhf, I didn't find any. So as a proof of insufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The converse of Lagrange's theorem holds for finite abelian groups. Here is an outline of a proof:

- Every finite abelian $p$-group is a product of cyclic subgroups and so the converse of Lagrange's theorem holds for abelian $p$-groups.
- Every finite abelian group is the product of its Sylow subgroups. By the previous result, the converse of Lagrange's theorem holds for all abelian groups.